# Is this too much inheritance/implementation?

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree

I'm designing a generic tree data structure in C# and I was wondering if I over designed it by having all those interfaces/classes:

```
public interface ITreeNode
{
    object GenericValue { get; }
    IEnumerable<ITreeNode> Children {get;}
}

public interface ITreeNode<T>:ITreeNode
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class TreeNode : ITreeNode
{
    protected readonly LinkedList<ITreeNode> _children = new LinkedList<ITreeNode>();
    protected object _value;

    public object GenericValue
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ITreeNode> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }
}

public class TreeNode<T> : TreeNode, ITreeNode<T>
{
    public T Value
    {
        get { return (T)base._value; }
    }
}
```

1. Could you please advice on improvements/simplifications?
2. How would you implement a binary tree node? Use another 2 interfaces and another 2 classes or is there a better way?

What is needed for: we need to store some trees that are connected to other trees. So, a leaf in one tree can be a root in another. That's why all those generics and non-generics

Comment: If you do not get enough useful answers, there is another StackExchange site for these types of questions: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looks good to me.  You might want to consider how it's going to be used in your business application to determine what flexibility is or is not needed.  For instance, if you always knew the type of value that will be stored, just use ITreeNode<T> and TreeNode<T>.

Comment: mellamokb, I added some more information

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you even need `TreeNode`? Why not use `TreeNode<object>` instead and then make `TreeNode<T>` type-safe without any casts whatsoever?

I think the interfaces here are fine.

Answer (score 0):

i would remove the *TreeNode < T >* class and relative interface: you could implement a template method quite easily casting a generic *object*. This would avoid one interace and one derivation whitout sacrifying readability.

The interface is good, since a class can't derive from *TreeNode*.

A note: binary tree are a specialization of N-ary trees.